# Remapping <c-]> for tags makes it ignore certain characters

Tags: vim

So I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap t <C-]>
```

This works perfectly fine for most cases but I recently noticed this: when trying to go to the following tag (cursor marked by `|`):

```
@user.cached_internally_opera|ted?
```

Pressing `t` results in: `E426: tag not found: cached_internally_operated`
and pressing `c-]` results in going to that tag.

Why is my remapping causing it to ignore the `?`?

Comment: Mapping a key which already has a meaning in `vim` already is a bad idea. `:help map-which-keys`

Comment: Do you have a (filetype) plugin that enhances the original mapping? Find out via `:nmap <C-]>`. If there is output, you need to use `:nmap` instead of `:nnoremap`.

Comment: Ingo, you were right! If you submit a response I'll approve it.

Comment: dlmeetei, I know. But it's my editor and I use it the way it works better for me. I never use the `t` movement unless is part of another command and this mapping doesn't shadow something like `ct"`.

Comment: Ah, great! It could really only be that (or a very strange bug in Vim). Added an answer with some more background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one explanation: You have a (filetype) plugin that enhances the original `<C-]>` mapping. You can find out via `:nmap <C-]>`. If there is output, you need to use `:nmap` instead of `:nnoremap`.

Normally, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion. However, if you define an alias to a custom command, or a built-in command that may be extended by a plugin, you have to use `:map`, so that the mapping applies.

Comment: Great explanation, both of the problem and the way to diagnose it, and excellent solution. Thank you!